# Accessing the Secure Vault Tool through Admin Service Enterprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, ei

Is it possible to configure entries using the Admin Services like you can do via the Secure Vault Tool in the Enterprise Integrator (ESB) admin page?

I currently use PowerShell scripts to install/configure WSO2, but need to now add values into the secure vault.

Many Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now come up with a solution to do this using PowerShell.

The steps I took are as follows:

1. Cloned the Cipher Tools github project and created a new version of CipherTools that allows parameters to be passed in, to remove the need for interacting and deleted the Console.readline() which caused me issues.
2. Created a new version of ciphertool.bat to make use of my new version of ciphertool.jar
3. Updated my PowerShell script to call my new version of ciphertool.bat capturing the response
4. Used the encrypted value I captured and stored it in WSO2 EI via the PropertiesAdminService

**Format for calling the new ciphertool.bat:**

ciphertool2.bat *StorePassword* *ValueToEncrypt*

**An example of the call to the new ciphertool.bat in PowerShell:**

$result =  .\ciphertool2.bat wso2carbon test